# Confusing about orbital speed

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

The Earth's distance from the Sun varies from $\ R_p=\ $ 1.471x$\ 10^8\ $km to $\ R_a=\ $ 1.521x$\ 10^8\ $km during the year. Determine the difference in the Earth-Sun system kinetic energy.

I have two different answers and I do not understand why at least one of them is incorrect (may be both).

Solution:
$\Delta\ E_K= \ m*v_2^2/2-m*v_1^2/2\ $;

---

1) Newton’s second law applied to the object of mass m gives:
$\ ma=mv^2/R=GmM_S/R^2;\ $

Multiplying both sides by R and dividing by m gives:
$\ v^2=GM_S/R\ $

$\Delta E_K= M_E*G*M_S*(1/R_a-1/R_p)/2 \ $

$\Delta E_K = 5.9736*10^{24}*6.67428*10^{-11}*1.9891*10^{30}*(1/(1.521*10^{11})-1/(1.471*10^{11}))/2 = -8.86*10^{31}J\ $

---

2) Orbital speed: $\ v=2*\pi*R/T\ $,   where T=365*24*3600 (sec)

$\Delta E_K^{'}=2*M_E*\pi^2/T^2*[R_a^2-R_p^2]\ $

$\Delta E_K^{'} = 2*5.9736*10^{24}*\pi^2/(365*24*3600)^2*((1.521*10^{11})^{2}-(1.471*10^{11})^{2})= 1.77*10^{32}J\ $

---

The first case has these orbital speed:
$\ v_a=\sqrt{GM_S/R_a}=\sqrt{6.67428*10^{-11}*1.9891*10^{30}/(1.521*10^{11}})=29544\ $ m/s  (aphelion)

and

$\ v_p=\sqrt{GM_S/R_p}=\sqrt{6.67428*10^{-11}*1.9891*10^{30}/(1.471*10^{11}})=30042\ $ m/s  (perihelion)

The second case:

$\ v_a^{'}=2*\pi*R_a/T=2*\pi*1.521*10^{11}/(365*24*3600)=30304\ $ m/s  (aphelion),

$\ v_p^{'}=2*\pi*R_p/T=2*\pi*1.471*10^{11}/(365*24*3600)=29308\ $ m/s  (perihelion).

The orbital speed at perihelion has to be always more than at aphelion. It means the second case is inappropriate for solving the issue.
Please explain where am I wrong?

Comment: At a quick look, I'd say it's because the equation $v=2\pi\frac{R}{T}$ is only applicable for circular motion, whereas the Earth is in an elliptical orbit

Comment: You are overcomplicating it. The total mechanical energy is conserved. The change in KE is the negative of change in PE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches are wrong because both assume a circular orbit. In the first one you make the assumption that the force is $mv^2/R$ which is only correct for uniform circular motion. In the second you assume that the speed is $2\pi R/T$ which is also only correct for uniform circular motion.

You can start with the vis viva equation. The most useful form will be 
$$v^2=GM\left(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\right)$$ where $a=(R_p+R_a)/2$ is the semi major axis.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation

Edit: or change in PE is even easier, as suggested by @nasu

Comment: Thanks Dale. I think @nasu answer fits better for solving that problem.

Comment: Agreed. The change in PE is easier than the vis viva equation.